# Store data got from javascript with node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I want to store the data i got from javascript with ajax in a folder to reuse them in my entire code, but i saw it was impossible to do with javascript and i work on local node.js server so do have any way to do that ?
i use twitch api and i receive an access token. I need to reuse it in other functions so i think the best way is to store this token.

i just discovered node.js so i don't understand how everything work.

Thank you

Comment: Why not get the data using node itself?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system,

Comment: I resolve my problem by getting my token in my node server.js file with this https://github.com/TwitchDev/authentication-samples/tree/master/node